# Alegreya font has 5 fonts with different boldness. How to make all of them usable with Latex?

Tags: fonts, bold

The Alegreya fonts are (i'm translating from German) "black" "very bold" "bold" "medium" and "standard". I have read about redefining semibold in bold, but I cannot find anything to make different versions of bold. How do I define 4 different bold versions. All of these have their italic counterparts. What has to be done for those?

Comment: which engine do you use?

Comment: pdflatex as always

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just list all the fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Alegreya}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  UprightFeatures={SmallCapsFont=*SC-Regular},
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  ItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont=*SC-Italic},
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldFeatures={SmallCapsFont=*SC-Bold},
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
  BoldItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont=*SC-BoldItalic},
  FontFace={sb}{n}{*-Medium},
  FontFace={sb}{it}{*-MediumItalic},
  FontFace={sb}{sc}{*SC-Medium},
  FontFace={sb}{scit}{*SC-MediumItalic},
  FontFace={ub}{n}{*-ExtraBold},
  FontFace={ub}{it}{*-ExtraBoldItalic},
  FontFace={ub}{sc}{*SC-ExtraBold},
  FontFace={ub}{scit}{*SC-ExtraBoldItalic},
  FontFace={k}{n}{*-Black},
  FontFace={k}{it}{*-BlackItalic},
  FontFace={k}{sc}{*SC-Black},
  FontFace={k}{scit}{*SC-BlackItalic},
]
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsemibold}{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textblack}{\fontseries{k}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textextrabold}{\fontseries{ub}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

Normal \textit{Italic} \textbf{Bold} \textbf{\textit{Bold Italic}}

\textsc{Small Caps} \textbf{\textsc{Bold SC}} \textit{\textsc{Italic SC}} \textbf{\textit{\textsc{Bold Italic SC}}}

\textsemibold{Medium} \textsemibold{\textit{Medium Italic}}

\textsemibold{\textsc{Medium SC}} \textsemibold{\textit{\textsc{Medium Italic SC}}}

\textextrabold{Extra Bold} \textextrabold{\textit{Extra Bold Italic}}

\textextrabold{\textsc{Extra Bold SC}} \textextrabold{\textit{\textsc{Extra Bold Italic SC}}}

\textblack{Black} \textblack{\textit{Black Italic}}

\textblack{\textsc{Black SC}} \textblack{\textit{\textsc{Black Italic SC}}}

\end{document}
```

Change the command names, if you prefer.

[image]

A table for better comparison.

[image]

#### pdflatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsemibold}{\AlegreyaMedium}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textblack}{\AlegreyaBlack}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textextrabold}{\AlegreyaExtraBold}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\sffamily}lll@{}}
\toprule
\sffamily Weight & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\sffamily Shape} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\sffamily Upright} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{\sffamily Italic} \\
\midrule
Normal & Normal & \textit{Italic} \\
Normal SC & \textsc{Small Caps} & \textit{\textsc{Italic SC}} \\
Medium & \textsemibold{Medium} & \textsemibold{\textit{Medium Italic}} \\
Medium SC & \textsemibold{\textsc{Medium SC}} & \textsemibold{\textit{\textsc{Medium Italic SC}}} \\
Bold & \textbf{Bold} & \textbf{\textit{Bold Italic}} \\
Bold SC & \textbf{\textsc{Bold SC}} & \textbf{\textit{\textsc{Bold Italic SC}}} \\
Extra Bold & \textextrabold{Extra Bold} & \textextrabold{\textit{Extra Bold Italic}} \\
Extra Bold SC & \textextrabold{\textsc{Extra Bold SC}} & \textextrabold{\textit{\textsc{Extra Bold Italic SC}}} \\
Black & \textblack{Black} & \textblack{\textit{Black Italic}} \\
Black SC & \textblack{\textsc{Black SC}} & \textblack{\textit{\textsc{Black Italic SC}}} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The table will be the same as the above one.

Comment: Does this also work with pdflatex? I never used xelatex or lualatex befor.

Comment: @bkleine It's even easier! See update

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really smart!

Comment: I have problems with the following, when I use scrbook, but not when using article as class.
 \documentclass[paper=A5]{scrbook}
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\newcommand{\ScN}[1]{\textsemibold{\textit{#1}}}%Scientific Names

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsemibold}{\AlegreyaMedium}
\begin{document}
 \textbf{\textit{Systema Naturae}}
 \begin{description}
  \item [\ScN{Polyommatus daphnis}(Zahnflügelbläuling)]  Dieser
 \end{description}
 \end{document}

Comment: @bkleine As far as I can see you just get a spurious warning.

Comment: I got rid of the warning with:  \setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{\normalfont\bfseries}. Now I would like to know: How can one define a switch \sbfseries which starts semibold instead of \bfseries which starts bold?